# Browser that can bookmark all tabs and supports multiple bookmarks for the same page

Tags: linux, web-browser, bookmark

Is there a browser (other than Safari) that supports the features for bookmark-all-tabs, and has a bookmark system that doesn't relocate bookmarks when i try to bookmark a single tab -- so I can have multiple entries for the same pages organized and grouped in different folders?

I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Opera now, and , as far as I can figure out, all 3 lack one or both of these features. I find these 2 features to be critically important to me researching on the web. I currently have these 2 features using Safari, but Safari seems to have gone away from cross-platform-support (going for Linux).

I have had some luck with [Midori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_(web_browser)) and while it does support duplicate bookmarks, it does not have a bookmark-all-tabs function.

Any suggestions?

Recently(jun/2021) I've discovered partial functionality in the browsers [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/), and [White Star](https://dbsoft.org/whitestar.php).

Answer (score 1):

**Firefox** offers both features:

- You can **bookmark all tabs** by right-clicking on the tab bar or a single tab. It will create a folder that contains bookmarks for all open tabs.
- You can create **multiple bookmarks for the same URL** and place them in different folders. Each of these bookmarks can have its own name and description, but the bookmark’s tags and search keyword will be shared.

  If you open the page and click on the boomark icon (the star), it shows how many bookmarks exist for this page’s URL, and it allows you to remove them all at once.

Comment: hey! looks like i overlooked a feature. It works on my macbook. is this feature also included in distributions for linux though?(can't check at the moment)

Comment: @kipbits: Yes (at least on Debian). As this is a basic Firefox feature (and not something that would typically be OS-specific), I guess it’s the case for all Firefox versions.

Comment: tested on latest OpenSUSE. save all tabs seams to work,(shift-alt-F) but if try to save just that bookmark it only gives me edit

Comment: @kipbits: It seems to depend on how you add the bookmark: If you click the bookmark icon (or press Ctrl+d), you can add the bookmark once, and after that edit the existing one(s). But if you drag-and-drop the URL (or the tab) into a folder (either on the symbol bar or in the Bookmarks menu), another bookmark will be created. Another possibility is to copy-and-paste a bookmark (either on the symbol bar or in the bookmark manager).

Comment: been playing with linux recently, and reminded me of this thread. The reason I could not find the button is because it is hidden(Alt + B) for some dumb reason.  https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox/bookmark-all-open-tabs/m-p/816681

Comment: Firefox 66 seems to have a bug with individual duplicate bookmarks: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1545915

Comment: sorry, did not read previous comments, although I think this is still relevant because I don't know existing solution for this in Firefox on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

This is supported on [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/).

This can bookmark all open tabs in what it calls a [*session*](https://vivaldi.com/features/).  Any saved session can then be reopened as required.
Individual sites can belong to several sessions.

Another useful feature is the ability to stack and group tabs, or to tile them within a window.

Vivaldi is available on Windows, Linux and Mac.